Handle missing/out of order packets in mediasource extension
I'm trying to play live video using mpegts.js. When there are missing packets or out of order packets, I see
Failed to execute 'appendBuffer' on 'SourceBuffer': The HTMLMediaElement.error attribute is not null

and the video stops
I'm getting the stream using a websocket connection. There's a destroyPlayer method on the player and when I call it, it closes websocket connection and I've added retry logic to create a new player and this opens a new websocket connection and this works.
But this causes few seconds of video to be missed and also, I don't want to create a new websocket connection. Also, I see this error in the console:
code: 3
message: "PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12909 \"(null)\" (-12909): VTDecompressionOutputCallback"


How do I handle this without creating a new websocket connection.

If the decoding libary cant handle this you need to validate the packages via a Buffer either in Frontend or Backend. You will only handle out of order packages when you had a timed buffer thingy. Because you will wait for them or not. Or skip packages. Thats always the reason why webdecoding is hard, because moast libs or apis give you the control like you had with ffmpeg.
